# Route to Controller and Set Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing the following in my routes.rb file:

```
match '/projects/:project_id/research/worksheet/:action' => 'worksheets/research'
```

What this route doesn't match, however, is /projects/whatever/research/worksheet => worksheets/research#index. I'm forced to add another line:

```
match '/projects/:project_id/research/worksheet' => 'worksheets/research#index'
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: The first line looks like an error to me, as you aren't matching the path to a controller AND action, just a controller.

Comment: When I match it to just a controller Rails will automatically match the :action to the corresponding action in the controller.